# CONSULTA: ¿Cómo guardar 1000 items en un carrito de compras?

Tags: php, sql, cookies

Muy buenos días colegas

Resulta que tengo un carrito de compras, y todos los datos los guardo en una cookie para después reutilizarlos en toda la web.

El problema es que no sabía que podían hacerse pedidos grandes como mas de +100 items, el principal problema es que mi cookie no aguanta tanta información.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que mi navegador me guarde 1,000 items en una cookie?, y al otro día que regrese ahí estén los mismo items, para confirmar la compra.

En este momento lo máximo que puedo insertar en la cookie son 20 items, desde ahí ya no entran más.

Está es mi imagen de la información que guardo en mi cookie.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien me podría dar una sugerencia de como podría realizar esa acción?
- Lo que yo había pensando era, solo guardar el id del producto, en la cookie y todo lo demás, generarlo en variables de sesión. ¿Creen que sea lo correcto?.

Saludos

Comment: Es considerablemente aconsejable guardar esos datos en una base de datos y estando asociada al usuario, así en cualquier plataforma y cualquier conexión, conservará su carrito, ademas es independiente a la plataforma de desarrollo.

Comment: Pero que pasa si al ultimo el usuario no compra nada, solo sería llenar mi base de datos a lo tonto. Saludos

Comment: Habría a lo sumo [Articulos]x[Usuarios] de lineas en esa tabla, asumiendo que "todos fueran a comprar todo pero ninguno completase la compra", ahora bien, puedes incluir en la estructura de esa tabla ([CodigoArticulo],[CodigoCliente],[Cantidad]) un atributo extra [FechaVencimiento], y las tareas de actualizacion y mantenimiento de éste. Dejando su fecha, por ejemplo, un mes adelante de la fecha actual en todo su carrito cada vez que ESE cliente agregue un articulo, y eliminar todas las lineas cuya fecha sea menor a la de hoy cada vez que... un usuario se conecta?, o una vez al mes?, y asi...

Comment: Igualmente, no considero que nadie juzgue la conservación de esos datos como un desperdicio de recursos, dado que simplemente son 3 atributos numéricos la tabla, y por lo tanto el espacio que ocupa y el rendimiento del motor de base de datos haciendo un JOIN con ella no disminuiría en lo absoluto. Y dado el caso, crear un indice seria suficiente (aunque para una tabla de 3 campos numéricos suena un despropósito)

Comment: Oh perfecto esa idea si me convence mucho, muchas gracias ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Guardar un carrito de compras en una COOKIE es una malísima idea. Deberías guardar los datos en la sesión del servidor web, o, mejor aun, en un repositorio persistente (como una base de datos).

Los *cookies* no fueron pensados para almacenar este tipo de información.

En PHP, para guardar en la sesión, podrías hacer algo como esto:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["carrito"] = $carrito;
// donde $carrito es una variable que contiene un JSON con el conenido
// del carrito, o una representación serializable similar
```

Luego, entre petición y petición,  puedes obtener información del carrito así:

```
$_SESSION["carrito"]; // acá está guardado el carrito.
```

Hay que destacar cierta documentación para utilizarla:

Para iniciar, reiniciar y obtener el id de sesion: [`session_start()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.session-start.php), [`session_regenerate_id()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.session-regenerate-id.php) y [`session_id()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.session-id.php).

Para almacenar en una variable de sesion, variables tipo array u objetos: [`serialize()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.serialize.php) y [`unserialize()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.unserialize.php)

Comment: Oh muchisimas gracias, pero que pasa si mi cliente apaga su computadora y regresa el otro día, las variables de sesión, no funcionarían para ese caso :c

Comment: Depende de cómo tengas configurada la sesión. Si guardas en la base de datos, definitivamente sí van a estar.